# Multi Table Aggregate Queries

Tags: ms-access

To avoid storing aggregate data I'm trying to create queries.  This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT ItemTransactions.ID, ItemTransactions.TransactionItem, ItemTransactions.TransactionType, ItemTransactions.Quantity, MasterInventory.QuantityOnHand, IIf([ItemTransactions]![TransactionType]=1,[MasterInventory]![QuantityOnHand]-[ItemTransactions]![Quantity],[MasterInventory]![QuantityOnHand]+[ItemTransactions]![Quantity]) AS [Current Quantity]FROM MasterInventory INNER JOIN ItemTransactions ON MasterInventory.ItemID = ItemTransactions.TransactionItem;
```

I've created that field QuantityOnHand in my master inventory, and this code works but just on the same initial QuantityOnHand field value.  What I'm shooting for in this example is to calculate from the initial QuantityOnHand value on the first iteration and then calculate from the "Current Quantity" value that the first iteration produced and so on.

Thank you.

Comment: Review http://allenbrowne.com/AppInventory.html

Comment: @June7. I've looked through this and I initially understand what he's saying, but I don't understand enough about SQL to comprehend how the DSUM() function works.  I'm going to take courses on VBA and SQL at this point.  Thanks!